# The class 'notranslate' is not working while using with select2 dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-translate, translate

I have been using google translate API in JavaScript, but when applying notranslate on select2 dropdown it not working, I also applied 'notranslate' class on options but still its not working.

what will be the probable solution please suggest...

Thank You !!!

Answer (score 0):

Add *notranslate* class on select option and add following script

```
$('.select2').select2().on('select2:open', function (e) {
            $('.select2-container').addClass('notranslate');
        });
```